# add a.link to jquery .css

Tags: jquery, css

I have a line where I add some css:

```
$("#foo").html("Some text with a link <a href=\"link.html\">Link here</a>").css({
     'margin': '10px 0px',
     'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px',
     'clear': 'left'
});
```

I want to change the link to the color black, so adding this css should work:

```
a.link {
     color: black
}
```

I guess the best thing to do is point to a css file instead of adding `a.link`. But wondering if it is possible. Obviously something like this doesn't work as it is not the proper json format:

```
$("#foo").html("Some text with a link <a href=\"link.html\">Link here</a>").css({
     'margin': '10px 0px',
     'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px',
     'clear': 'left',
     'a:link: color': 'black'
 });
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: _as it is not the proper json format_? You are passing a regular JavaScript object not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not insert a style tag with needed styles? `<style type="text/css">a.link: {color: black}</style>` or define link color inline

```
$("#foo").html('Some text with a link <a style="color: black" href="link.html">Link here</a>').css({'margin': '10px 0px', 'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px', 'clear': 'left'});
```

`.css` is used to defined inline css styles, not styles by selectors, like `a.link`, use `<style>` tag for that.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot update a style for child element from the parent elements css function. Instead why not add it to the css file,

```
#foo a.link { color: black; }
```

In case if you are curious on how to add it by script..

```
$("#foo")            //Added class link to the link tag--v
   .html('Some text with a link <a href=\"link.html\" class="link">Link here</a>')
   .css({'margin': '10px 0px', 'padding': '15px 10px 15px 50px', 'clear': 'left'})
   .find('a.link').css({'color': 'black'}); 
   //^-- this would find the link tag and updates its css
```